# Adding many picture in a row in gridview

Tags: android, gridview

i want to add 9 picture in a row in this grid view . How should i approach i have read this article http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html  .Please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the place of `android:numColumns="auto_fit"`

you use

```
 android:numColumns="9"
```